# Function to find the median of a vector?

Tags: c, median

I am trying to write a function that finds the median of a given array. I am having an issue where it doesnt output the proper values for either even or odd when its unsorted to begin with. Sorted inputs work however. Does anyone see whats wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
double vect_median( const double x[], unsigned length)
{
    double ordered[LENGTH] = {0}; //new vector to hold the ordered items, use of {} to accommodate larger sizes
    int temp = 0; //var to hold the value of an item for re-arrangement
    float result = 0;

    for (size_t k = 0; k < length; ++k)
    {
        ordered[k] = x[k];
    }


    for (size_t i = 1; i < length; ++i) //loops to order the values of the vector, start at 1 because length != 0
    {
        for (size_t n = 0; n < (length - 1); ++n) //loop to indivudally check each value
        {
            if (ordered[n] > ordered[n + 1]) //if first is greater than second
            {
                temp = ordered[n];  //switch the order of the two values
                ordered[i] = ordered[i + 1];
                ordered[i+1] = temp;

            }
        }

        //once a value is switched, the loops breaks and the outside loop runs it again LENGTH times
        if(length % 2 == 1)//if odd
        {
            result = ordered[LENGTH/2]; //return the val in the middle of the dataset
        }
        else
        {
            result = (ordered[LENGTH/2] + ordered[LENGTH/2 - 1])/2;

        }
    }  
      return(result);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to **debug your code using break points** or adding print statements

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/ for a better algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong because it uses `i` after making a decision based on `n`:

```
        if (ordered[n] > ordered[n + 1]) //if first is greater than second
            {
                temp = ordered[n];  //switch the order of the two values
                ordered[i] = ordered[i + 1];
                ordered[i+1] = temp;

            }
```

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that